# Why does Sass incorrectly convert css content?

Tags: css, sass

I have the following rule in my .scss file:

```
.listing-price:before {
   ...
   content: "♥";
```

For whatever reason, running `sass --update foo.scss:foo.css --style expanded` converts it to:

```
.listing-price:before {
   ...
   content: "ΓÖÑ";
```

Why does this happen and what do I need to do to prevent it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sass should be auto-detecting character encoding on your documents. If not for some reason, you can explicitly set it to UTF-8 using `@charset "UTF-8";`

**From the SASS docs:**

> When running on Ruby 1.9 and later, Sass is aware of the character encoding of documents. Sass follows the CSS spec to determine the encoding of a stylesheet, and falls back to the Ruby string encoding. This means that it first checks the Unicode byte order mark, then the @charset declaration, then the Ruby string encoding. If none of these are set, it will assume the document is in UTF-8.
>
> To explicitly specify the encoding of your stylesheet, use a @charset declaration just like in CSS. Add @charset "encoding-name"; at the beginning of the stylesheet (before any whitespace or comments) and Sass will interpret it as the given encoding. Note that whatever encoding you use, it must be convertible to Unicode.
>
> Sass will always encode its output as UTF-8. It will include a @charset declaration if and only if the output file contains non-ASCII characters. In compressed mode, a UTF-8 byte order mark is used in place of a @charset declaration.

```
@charset "UTF-8";
.listing-price:before {
    content: "♥";
}
```

**Demo:**

https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/6326e75075795d1c265d26467c06518c

**Docs:**

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html

Comment: Thank you.  The key (that I missed the 1st time around) is that the @charset declaration has to be absolute first thing in the file, before any comments.

Comment: It did cause me to download the latest SASS compiler.

Answer (score 4):

Set

```
@charset "utf-8";
```

at the top of your scss files where you use characters in the UTF range

https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1663